# Mockito produces StackOverflowError when mocked method is called in equals()/hashCode()

Tags: java, mockito

This example code:

```
public final class FooBarTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
        when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(1);
        new HashSet().add(foo);
    }

    private class Foo {
        @Override
        public final boolean equals(final Object other) {
            return getBar() == 0;
        }

        public int getBar() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public final int hashCode() {
            return getBar();
        }
    }
}
```

produces an endless loop and throws an exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:119)
    at de.weltraumschaf.maconha.FooBarTest$Foo$MockitoMock$217383798.getBar(Unknown Source)
    at de.weltraumschaf.maconha.FooBarTest$Foo.equals(FooBarTest.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.matches(InvocationMatcher.java:81)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl.findAnswerFor(InvocationContainerImpl.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:90)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:119)
    at de.weltraumschaf.maconha.FooBarTest$Foo$MockitoMock$217383798.getBar(Unknown Source)
    at de.weltraumschaf.maconha.FooBarTest$Foo.equals(FooBarTest.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.matches(InvocationMatcher.java:81)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl.findAnswerFor(InvocationContainerImpl.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:90)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:119)
    at de.weltraumschaf.maconha.FooBarTest$Foo$MockitoMock$217383798.getBar(Unknown Source)
    at de.weltraumschaf.maconha.FooBarTest$Foo.equals(FooBarTest.java:24)
    ...
```

I debugged into the code and got lost in the depth of Mockito. The only thing I can see is that the equals method is called right. I know that Mockito does not stub `equals`/`hashCode`/`toString`. It is also clear to me that the `equals` method is called by the HashSet to see if there is already an equal element in it. But what I can't figure out: Why does this loop endless?

The used Mockito version is 2.8.9 and JUnit 4.12.

Comment: May be due to Mockito using the `equals` method itself ti verify that it's the same object. What happens if you don't override the hash and equals for the sake of whittling down the issue? Mockito may not be the best usecase for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the callstack there is `org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher#matches` which basically is
`invocation.getMock().equals(candidate.getMock())` (with `invocation.getMock()` being your mocked `Foo` instance) which causes a call to `getBar` which is mocked which causes a call to `equals` -> `getBar` -> mock -> `equals` -> `getBar` -> etc...